# Postgresql pattern check constraint

Tags: regex, postgresql, check-constraints

I have a project for uni, and I wondered, how can I make an constraint that checks exact format of a string. So far, all my tries failed.
Latest version of code is

```
CREATE TABLE study_courses(
course_id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
course_title VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
course_code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL CHECK(course_code LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
credit_points INT);
```

course_code should match a pattern of XXXX0000
There is another field in my database, that needs to match a pattern of XX00000 , I have tried something like

```
matriculation_number VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL CHECK (MatriculationNumber SIMILAR TO '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}')
```

And it does not work either.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: You're comparing against a regex so you should use the ~ operator. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html

Comment: Thank you! It worked!

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regex